# JAVA JPanel not displaying image

Tags: java, jpanel, bufferedimage, imageicon

I am currently playing around with reading an image (a google street view) from a url and adding it to a JPanel. To start, I am taking the url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988" and trying to read an image from it then add this image to a jpanel I will display. I am not receiving any compilation or runtime errors, however the JPanel never pops up so I cannot tell if my image is on it or not. Any ideas here?

Edit: To clarify, I want to pop up a new window containing the image read in from the URL, not add the image to an existing panel

```
URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988");
BufferedImage streetView  = ImageIO.read(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(streetView));
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(label);
panel.setLocation(0,0);
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @cbender I make a label from an imageicon created from the buffered image, then add the label to the panel... is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: I have one stupid question: did you add this panel to any frame which you make visible?

Comment: I'm with @Pshemo, in that the problem may be with your JPanel panel variable. I suggest that you simplify and get rid of the panel JPanel variable as it serves no purpose other than to confuse. Instead add the image to a JLabel that has already been added to the GUI. And no, don't display another JFrame as someone has suggested in an answer.

Comment: maybe i was not as clear as I should have been. I want to pop up a new window which will display this image in the URL, not add it to an existing frame

Comment: Also you mention, `" however the JPanel never pops up..."` -- why would you expect it to? Edit, you state: `"I want to pop up a new window which will display this image in the URL, not add it to an existing frame"` -- then display it in a JOptionPane.

Comment: I would expect it to because I have instantiated it and call setVisible on it. Why wouldn't I expect it to? Duely noted on the JOptionPane I didn't think about using it to display an image I will look into this

Comment: So if you will instantiate element like `JButton` and call `setVisable(true)` would you also expect it to appear somewhere on screen? How would you close this button later?

Comment: It all makes sense now :) thanks all. very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pop up a new window which will display this image in the URL, not add it to an existing frame

I asked why you would expect this to display as a window, and you stated,

> I would expect it to because I have instantiated it and call setVisible on it.

Understand that a JPanel is a container component that holds other components but doesn't have the machinery to display a full GUI. To do this you would need to place it into some type of top-level window such as a JFrame, JDialog, JApplet or JOptionPane or into another container that is displayed in a top level window.

Then create a dialog window and display the image in it. Simplest would be a JOptionPane:

```
URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988");
BufferedImage streetView  = ImageIO.read(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(streetView));
// JPanel panel = new JPanel();
// panel.add(label);

// code not needed:
// panel.setLocation(0,0);
// panel.setVisible(true);

// mainGuiComponent is a reference to a component on the main GUI
// or null if there is no main GUI.
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainGuiComponent, label);
```

Note that you could just pass the ImageIcon into the JDialog and it would be sufficient too

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainGuiComponent, myImageIcon);
```

Comment: perfect thank you. very informative also. As a followup question, how/why does passing null in as the parent component still allow my JOptionPane to display?

Comment: @peggy: A JOptionPane is really a JDialog or "sub"-window in disguise, and the first parameter is used by Swing to assign a  parent window to the dialog, a window that the dialog will lock and prevent user interaction until the JDialog has been closed. If you pass in `null`, Swing creates (I believe) a non-displayed JFrame to act as the parent window of the dialog. Note that I'm not 100% sure of the latter, and will need to double check it for accuracy. I do know that null works, but should not be used if you are showing the JOptionPane from another Swing window.

Answer (score 2):

A JPanel by itself will not popup and display anything.  You need to add it to a parent window, such as a JFrame or a JDialog.

```
URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988");
BufferedImage streetView  = ImageIO.read(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(streetView));
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(label);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

That should get you started.